# Error al insertar datos a una tabla en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema con la inserción de los siguientes datos en la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE TB_ADMIN_MONITOREO
(
    FECHA_PROCESO   NVARCHAR,
    FECHA_EJECUCION DATETIME,
    SERVIDOR        NVARCHAR,
    UNIDAD          CHAR,
    [LIBRE (MB)]    DECIMAL(15,2),
    [LIBRE (GB)]    DECIMAL(15,2),
    ESTADO          NVARCHAR
)
------------------------------------------------------------

insert TB_ADMIN_MONITOREO
values('20180423',GETDATE(), 'NEPTUNO','D',12.36, 45.23, 'RIESGO')
```

Resultado:

```
Mens. 8152, Nivel 16, Estado 4, Línea 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Ya he probado con `Varchar`, `Nvarchar` y no me funciona ninguno de ellos. No estoy seguro cual sea el origen del problema.

Saludos

Comment: **nunca** uses `varchar` o `nvarchar` sin declarar el largo que quieres; por ejemplo; `nvarchar(20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por el tipo de datos que estas utilizando , se truncan los datos si envías un valor mayor a la longitud ya que los valores de longitud no estan definidos..

```
DECLARE  @TB_ADMIN_MONITOREO TABLE
(
    FECHA_PROCESO   DATETIME,
    FECHA_EJECUCION DATETIME,
    SERVIDOR        VARCHAR(50),
    UNIDAD          CHAR(1),
    [LIBRE (MB)]    DECIMAL(15,2),
    [LIBRE (GB)]    DECIMAL(15,2),
    ESTADO          VARCHAR(10)
)
------------------------------------------------------------

insert @TB_ADMIN_MONITOREO
values('20180423',GETDATE(), 'NEPTUNO','D',12.36, 45.23, 'RIESGO')

SELECT * FROM @TB_ADMIN_MONITOREO
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en que no se ha definido el largo del campo es decir debes decir `nvarchar(250)`

```
CREATE TABLE TB_ADMIN_MONITOREO
(
    FECHA_PROCESO   NVARCHAR(25),
    FECHA_EJECUCION DATETIME,
    SERVIDOR        NVARCHAR(75),
    UNIDAD          CHAR,
    [LIBRE (MB)]    DECIMAL(15,2),
    [LIBRE (GB)]    DECIMAL(15,2),
    ESTADO          NVARCHAR(50)
)
```